# Prevent data loss when migrating from CKEditor 4 to 5

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5, ckeditor4.x

Seems like a dumb question but the CKEditor migration docs simply say "Extensive analysis, data verification and tests should be performed on existing data" without offering much more help and I cannot find anything online?

What are some things ya'll have done. Simply keeping CKEditor 4 for existing data is not an option for my project.

Our implementation is pretty basic with only 3 plugins that are covered in CKE 5 configurations. Nothing custom however we do use `config.allowedContent = true;` in our config, which might be a problem